# page cut command in php for POS printers

Tags: php, javascript

Im working on a project where i need to use POS printer to generate the reciept. The client asked for a new request where the paper need to be cut automatically when the print has been done.. so that if he needs to print 10 recipts at a time it cuts 10 times and makes some difference.

Comment: Do you think PHP / Javascript can achieve this ? You have to tell the POS printer driver to cut the receipt.

Comment: but my application was based on php how can i solve this problem now?

Comment: You can't. Contact the manufacturer of the POS printer for help.

Comment: Many of these printers use proprietary commands for this sort of thing.  You need to post the command reference if you expect any help.  It's specific to the model of printer you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am having to make a few assumptions here.

- The POS printer is connected to the client computer, not the PHP
  server.
- This is an internal application supporting Windows based POS terminals.

With this said, there are several Serial/COM port plugins available. We currently use an ActiveX plugin at work, though I wont make any recommendations -- I don't know enough about the alternatives. This will need to be installed/approved by the client computer.

Find the Make/Model of your printer and find the control codes for cutting the paper. They should be listed in the back of the manual. You will need to program your PHP script to output the correct data/control codes to the plugin to send to the printer.

Just for the record, I am not a fan of this solution.